# "raspberry" password denied first ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I've followed the guideline explaining how to install Raspberry Pi Os (for my RPi 4 model B) from the official website. I installed first the light version and then the recommended one. I added the empty `ssh` files and the `wpa_supplicant.conf` (also tried to connect with ethernet) to the boot.

I am able to ping my RPi (IP=192.168.0.10) and obtain an ssh connection but I could not successfully login because the `raspberry` password would always be denied. I am pretty sure the IP is correct and have rebooted a couple of times already. What have I missed to make the ssh connection work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing Buster? The [pi/raspberry combination is deprecated](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/). I suggest using the [Raspberry Pi imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-imager-imaging-utility/) which allows you to set a username/password before burning the image.